# Is there an example to build a Antlr4 Grammar/Parser for Oracle PL SQL with the Go runtime target?

Tags: go, plsql, antlr4

I'm looking to build a lexer/parser for Oracle PL SQL using the Go target. I tried using the ANTLR plsql grammer in GitHub (antlr/grammars-v4/sql/plsql), but have run into a few issues. When I run the tooling to create the lecer and parser I get errors and will not run because of the errors.Some struts seem to be missing.

I ran the following command for the lexer/parser: **antlr -Dlanguage=Go -o parser PlSqlLexer.g4**.
Getting errors like: undeclared name: PlSqlLexerBase and l.BaseLexer undefined.
I'm not able to proceed with building the listeners until these errors are resolved. I did download to files in the GO directory, but they didn't seem to make a difference.
I'm looking for instructions on how to build the parser.

Comment: Not for sql, but here is an example parser generated for another language using go:generate: https://github.com/cloudprivacylabs/opencypher/blob/main/lang.go#L11

Comment: The [grammars-v4/sql/plsql](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/plsql) currently seems to only work for CSharp, Java. JavaScript. (I am updating all grammars with a description of what targets the grammar works with.) There are [Go files](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/87bcdac9d4487e73ac6566d07e44161915c2bb85/sql/plsql/Go) for the base classes needed for the grammar, but it seems those aren't working. For example, it references Antlr 4.10 not 4.11, which has a major fix for Go. Raise the issue in grammars-v4, and I'll try to fix the port today.

Comment: I have an initial port of the plsql grammar to Go working I think (at least it builds and runs on one test case). https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/plsql/Generated-Go

Comment: Sorry, one other thing. You have to use all the options `-o`, `-lib`, and `-package` for the command line call to generate the parser source code. This is because the Go target templates insist on a package declaration, and Golang's insistence of the files contained in a directory of the same name as the package name. `java -jar "C:/Users/Kenne/.m2/antlr4-4.11.1-complete.jar" -encoding utf-8 -Dlanguage=Go -o parser -lib parser -package parser  parser/PlSql*.g4`

Comment: @kayby76 Thanks for yo help. I was able to build the parser using your files. I created a new main and created a listener to process the file. I didn't do anything to your code. I just copied the files from the parser directory. Unfortunately, I don't think I've got the right SQL grammar. When I run the DDL file, I'm getting errors. I think the grammar doe not support the DDL I was given. Here are some of the statements that didn't work.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "X"."Y" 
   ( "OID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "STANDARDIZED_HOME_PHONE" GENERATED ALWAYS AS (115) VIRTUAL , 
   ) ;
CREATE TABLE "A"."B" 
   ( "FIELD1" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "FIELD2" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  PRIMARY KEY ("FIELD1") ENABLE
   )  ORGANIZATION INDEX NOCOMPRESS ; It didn't like the ORGANIZATION key word and did not like the GENERATED claues. If anyone knows which SQL grammar to use , it would be greatly appreciates. Otherwise, I might have to edit or preprocess the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using ANTLR v4 to build a lexer/parser for a simple arithmetic expression grammar in Go:

First, install ANTLR v4 and set up the environment variables.

Create a new ANTLR grammar file, for example "Arithmetic.g4", and define the grammar rules:

```
grammar Arithmetic;

expr: term ((PLUS | MINUS) term)* ;
term: factor ((MUL | DIV) factor)* ;
factor: INT | LPAREN expr RPAREN ;

PLUS: '+' ;
MINUS: '-' ;
MUL: '*' ;
DIV: '/' ;
INT: [0-9]+ ;
LPAREN: '(' ;
RPAREN: ')' ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Run the following command to generate the lexer and parser code in Go:

```
antlr -Dlanguage=Go -o parser Arithmetic.g4
```

In your Go program, import the generated parser and lexer packages and use them to parse the input expression:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr"
    "os"
    "your-path-to-generated-parser/parser"
)

// Define a custom listener that implements the PlSqlListener interface
type PlSqlListener struct {
    *parser.BasePlSqlListener
}

func (l *PlSqlListener) EnterSql_statement(ctx *parser.Sql_statementContext) {
    // Your implementation to handle SQL statements
}

func (l *PlSqlListener) EnterPlsql_block(ctx *parser.Plsql_blockContext) {
    // Your implementation to handle PL/SQL blocks
}

func main() {
    // Create the input stream
    input := antlr.NewInputStream("DECLARE\nBEGIN\nDBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');\nEND;")

    // Create the lexer
    lexer := parser.NewPlSqlLexer(input)
    stream := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, 0)

    // Create the parser
    p := parser.NewPlSqlParser(stream)

    // Start the parse tree
    tree := p.Compilation_unit()

    // Create the custom listener and attach it to the parse tree
    listener := &PlSqlListener{}
    antlr.ParseTreeWalkerDefault.Walk(listener, tree)
}
```

This is a basic example to show how to build a lexer/parser for Oracle PL/SQL. You can modify the custom listener to handle different PL/SQL statements and blocks as needed.